# FCM API returns a success response but push notification is not delivered to user

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification using FCM legacy API and by request looks like the following

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

{
 "to" : "USER-DEVICE-TOKEN",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Getting this?",
     "title": "Let me know if you got this message",
     "icon": "ic_launcher"
 },
 "data": {
    "one": "two"
 }
}
```

This request returns the following response

```
{
    "multicast_id": 144107415xxxxxxxxx,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1581xxxxx5%32xxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the user never receives any push notification. This happens for most of the user but about 10% of total user does receive push notification send by the same mechanism. I am out of sorts regarding this, I don't know whats going on or even how to go about debugging this. Has anyone run into this issue? The app is written in React Native and uses invertase/react-native-firebase for firebase features. Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to log the notification from all listeners e.g background listener & foreground listener ?
I believe you've to manually show the alert if your App is in foreground. Maybe this is what you're missing.

Comment: I have a listener that get triggers when app is in foreground. I checked firebase reports and the delivery rate is less than 10%, that makes me think there is something else going on.